# Printing / math on Python gambling game?

Tags: python, math, printing

So I ran into trouble with this code again with output. Basically, there are some key features I need it to print, but whenever I manage to get it to print one thing it completely messes up the rest of the printing. So for example, I need it to print `Roll # 1 (1 - 3) was (whatever number)` not `Roll (whatever number)` if that makes sense. But I also need it to only max out to 3 rolls. This is where my second issue comes in; whenever I try to code it to subtract the bet from the bank when a user doesn't match any rolls, it counts my subtraction as a fourth roll and screws up the math. So instead of `Roll #1` through `#3` its now up to `Roll #4`
My third problem is, I need to the program to continue looping until the user enters `0 (zero)` to end the script or the bank amount reaches `0 (zero)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should redesign your program. First of all, you are generating new results for each condition check at

```
if guess == rollDice():
        bank = bet * 2
    elif guess == rollDice():
        bank += bet * .5
    elif guess == rollDice():
        bank = bank
```

Your code is not properly indented.

```
   [...]
   elif guess == rollDice():
        bank += bet * .5
    elif guess == rollDice():
        bank = bank
else:
    guess != rollDice()
    bank = bank - bet
    print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
    print(f'Thanks for playing!')
```

And so on...

---

Have a function that simulates a single dice roll, like:

```
def roll():
    return random.randint(1, 6)
```

And handle the rest in your main function like:

```
prog_info()
while True: #main loop
    rolls = list() #redefines after each loop
    score = 2
    for i in range(3): #3 dice roll
        bank, bet = total_bank(bank)
        guess = get_guess()
        if not guess: #exit condition
            break
        rolls.append(roll())
        if sum(rolls) == guess:
            bank = bet * score
            break #break on match
        score = score - 0.5 #after each roll we have less money to win
    print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
    print(f'Thanks for playing!')
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple changes get the result you want

- Pass the roll count to the `rollDice` function
- Add an `else` to the bottom of the if block to check 0 bank

Here is the updated code:

```
import random

def rollDice(cnt):
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    x = int(die1 + die2)
    print('Roll #', cnt, 'was', x)
    return x

def prog_info():
    print("My Dice Game .v02")
    print("You have three rolls of the dice to match a number you select.")
    print("Good Luck!!")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print(f'You will win 2 times your wager if you guess on the 1st roll.')
    print(f'You will win 1 1/2 times your wager if you guess on the 2nd roll.')
    print(f'You can win your wager if you guess on the 3rd roll.')
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

def total_bank(bank):
    bet = 0
    while bet <= 0 or bet > min([500,bank]):
        print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
        get_bet = input('Enter your bet (or 0 to quit): ')
        if get_bet == '0': 
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            exit()
        bet = int(get_bet)
    return bank,bet

def get_guess():
    guess = 0
    while (guess < 2 or guess > 12):
        try:
            guess = int(input('Choose a number between 2 and 12: '))
        except ValueError:
            guess = 0
        return guess

prog_info()
bank = 500
guess = get_guess

while True:
    rcnt = 0
    bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess == rollDice(rcnt+1):
        bank += bet * 2
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+2):
        bank += bet * .5
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+3):
        bank = bank
    else:
        bank = bank - bet  # no match
        if bank == 0: 
           print('You have no money left. Thanks for playing!')
           exit()
```

Output

```
You have $500 in your bank.
Enter your bet (or 0 to quit): 500
Choose a number between 2 and 12: 4
Roll # 1 was 11
Roll # 2 was 6
Roll # 3 was 7
You have no money left. Thanks for playing!
```